# how to assign a group of logical Linux interfaces to a Docker container?

Tags: docker, linux-containers, docker-network

I'm running multiple Docker containers (C1, C2, C3..... ) on a Linux based switch/router. The switch has 24 front-panel ports.

I'd like to assign the first 4 ports (**eth1 - eth4**) to container C1,
the next 4 ports (**eth5 - eth8**) to container C2,
the next 4 ports (**eth9 - eth12**) to container C3....and so on.
Essentially, I want all control plane traffic ingressing on physical ports (**eth1 - eth4**) to be handled by container C1.
How can I achieve this ?

As per my understanding, native Docker networking uses NAT based on L4 ports and does not support this scenario.

I'm running Docker Version: 1.9.0 , Linux Kernel 3.18

I hope this would be of interest to anyone running Docker Containers on a Linux Switch/Router.